# Telephony Operations on Federally Enrolled U.S. Indian Reservations

Tags: united-states, telemarketing

> **Question:** Are telephony operations on [Federally Enrolled Native American Indian Reservations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_federally_recognized_tribes) exempt from the
>   [Telephone Consumer Protection Act of 1991](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_Consumer_Protection_Act_of_1991)  ?

Are there any interpretations of TCPA-91; which would allow one to infer that telephony operations within the boundaries of a federally enrolled US Native Indian Tribe are exempt from the act ? For example are telephony operations "on the rez" allowed to make contacts to phone numbers on the "[do not call list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Do_Not_Call_Registry)."